# Webrequest cant "escape" timeout

Tags: c#, timeout, httpwebrequest, webrequest, internet-connection

Hi everyone im trying to create a method that will always return a url source, if for example internet goes off it will continue working until it comes up and return the url source and so on if something else occurs. So far in my method when i "turn off" the internet and "turn it on" back procedures continue normaly **but im having an issue when a timeout occurs and im "falling" in a loop** i know that the while(true) is not the right approach but im using it for my tests.

So how can i skip the timeout exception and "retry" my method?

```
public static async Task<string> GetUrlSource(string url)
{
    string source = "";
    while (true)
    {
        HttpWebRequest hwr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        hwr.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        hwr.UserAgent = UserAgent;
        hwr.Headers.Add(hd_ac_lang[0], hd_ac_lang[1]);
        hwr.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        hwr.Timeout = 14000;
        try
        {
            using (var response = hwr.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    source = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                    if (check_source(source))
                    {
                        return source;
                    }
                 }
             }
         }
         catch (WebException ex)
         {
             hwr.Abort();
             if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
             {
                if (((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode == HttatusCode.NotFound)
                {
                    // handle the 404 here
                    return "404";
                 }
              }
              else
              {
                 Console.WriteLine(ex.Status.ToString());    
              }
         }
    }
}
```

**Note:** i used to have the hwr.Abort(); into a finnaly clause but it didnt help.

**Edit:** the console is writting this message every 14 seconds as my timeout i think its something related with that.

Comment: Whats wrong with your current method? Your timeout causes an exception and you loop back around?

Comment: @CathalMF I dont know either but after the 1st timeout it seems that is falls in a loop. Its like the hwr after that its forever in a timeout state.

Comment: Are you sure its not your Server end which is breaking causing the timeout loop?

Comment: Actually im running this app locally, and the truth is that im having some internet issues but despite that, if at the same moment i restart the app it runs normally. Btw the exception is running every 14 seconds so its like its not releasing some resources or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

ِAn alternative solution to get rid of timeout problem can be is to use `WebBrowser` component and to navigate to the required url(`webbrowser1.Navigate(url);`) ,and to wait in a loop until the `documentcompleted` event is raised and then to get the source code by this line :

```
string source = webbrowser1.DocumentText;
```

Comment: Well im guessing that this could do the work, but i want to fix my method and find the reason behind my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems that i found a solution that was related with the service point of the request.

So in my catch when a timeout occurs im using this to release the connection.

```
hwr.ServicePoint.CloseConnectionGroup(hwr.ConnectionGroupName);
```

I'll keep this updated.